# Using output of one python file in other

Tags: python, twitter

I am using the following code available on internet for streaming tweets.

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json

ckey= ""
csecret =""
atoken     =""
asecret    =""

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        for each in data:
            return (json.loads(data))
        return(True)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car","python"])
```

I want to use the ouput of this code(stream of tweets) in other program and perform operation on each tweet in the stream. How can I do this?
for example in other program i might want to do:

```
for eachtweet:
    print(eachtweet['text'])
```

Comment: Is there a reason you just aren't importing the class/function you need into the other program?

Comment: i tried doing from file1 import listener and then jus executing the program is giving output. I want to import it to some variable and then want to access it like 
 for each in var:
    print(each['text'])

Comment: I would move all the code thats not in the class to the other py file, and then you can import the class/function, run, and then deal with results as needed. If you import a py file with code that's not in a class/function, that code will automatically get executed.